# I don't know why I keep getting the error 'str' has not attribute 'message'

Tags: python, class, attributeerror, self

```py
from plyer import notifications

class Reminder():
    def __init__(self,message = None):

        if not message:
            message = input("Please enter the message: ")

        self.message = message
        print(self.message)

    def sendNotification(self):
        print(self.message)
        notification.notify(title = "Python reminder", message = self.message, app_name = "Python reminder program",app_icon = "",timeout = 10,ticker = "this is ticker thing")

    def getTime(self):
        pass



Reminder.sendNotification("message")
```

The error that I am getting is as follows:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/yomamahahaha/Desktop/oooohackrrr/actual programs/python/Reminders/reminder.py", line 28, in 
Reminder.sendNotification("kek")
File "c:/Users/yomamahahaha/Desktop/oooohackrrr/actual programs/python/Reminders/reminder.py", line 20, in sendNotification
print(self.message)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'message'

Comment: What about sharing the part of the code that's actually giving you the error? There's no line 28 in what you gave us. You're also not initializing an instance of the class (assuming `Reminder` is not a variable but an attempt to instantiate the class). You're also passing a message to the `sendNotification` method, which doesn't take arguments. It should be like this: `Reminder('message').sendNotification()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't create an instance of Reminder

so when you call

```
Reminder.sendNotification("message")
```

You're setting 'self' as "message" here: Then calling `"message".message` , which doesn't exist

```
def sendNotification(self):
    print(self.message)
```

I think you mean

```
myReminder = Reminder("Message")
myReminder.sendNotification()
```